# Remove 64-bit Internet Explorer from Windows XP 32-bit system

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, uninstall

I need to remove 64-bit IE from a Windows XP Pro 32-bit system.  Can I just install the 32-bit version with 64-bit and pick 32-bit as default?

Then uninstall 64-bit version?  This is not on my PC, it's on my boss'.  I don't want to mess up.

Comment: How did you get 64-bit IE onto a 32-bit OS in the first place?

Comment: @squillman: Skillz, probably.

Comment: @Mehrdad Heh, dem's mad skilz

Answer (score 0):

You have done something very wrong as 64 bit Windows can not install on 32 bit Windows.

64 Bit Internet Explorer will not install on 32 Bit Windows, if you just have the installer, you can delete it without problems.

However, if you do have a 64 bit system and simply want to remove it, take a look in `Add or Remove Programs`, and click on `View Installed Updates` take a look there and Internet Explorer is listed.

That being said, I am not aware of a way to actually choose between editions and I am pretty sure both are installed by default.